# Not enough arguments missing name when i make seed Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php

i am trying to make a seed with:

```
php artisan make:seed
```

But, i get the error:

```
Not enough arguments (missing: "name").
```

I dont know why, this is the seed i am trying to make:

```
class ProfessionSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('professions')->insert([
            'title' => 'Desarrollador Back End'
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is the migration corresponding to the DB table...

```
class CreateProfessionsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('professions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->string('title', 100);


            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Any ideas of what is going on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see what is required for a command by using `artisan help`:

```
php artisan help make:seed
```

Will output something like:

```
Description:
  Create a new seeder class

Usage:
  make:seeder <name>

Arguments:
  name                  The name of the class
...
```

This command takes an argument for the name of the class you want to create.

```
php artisan make:seed ProfessionSeeder
```